# Using typedef in a header file

Tags: c, typedef

So I am trying to define data in a header file, using typedef. Specifically, I need to point the headerfile code below to my main file. I have no idea how to go about doing this.  I am getting an error saying that "(all data types defined in the header file) are undeclared (first use this function.)" Can anybody point me in the right direction? Thank you!

EDIT: The CalcTaxes.o file is just an external file that passes information.  It should have no effect on the following code.

Below is the header file:

```
typedef char STR15[15+1];
typedef char STR10[10+1];
typedef struct EmployeeRecord 
{
   STR15 lastname;
   STR10 firstname;
   float hours,
   payrate,
   defr,
   gross,
   fedtax,
   statetax,
   ssitax,
   net;
} EmployeeRecord;
```

And below is the main file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "EmployeeRecord.h"
#include "CalcTaxes.o"
#define ADDR(var) &var
#define REPORTCOLUMNHEADINGS1 "Employee           Pay    Reg Hrs  Gross    Fed     SSI     Net\n"
#define REPORTCOLUMNHEADINGS2 "Name               Rate   OVT Hrs  Pay      State   Defr    Pay\n"
#define BARS                  "========           =====  =======  =======  ======  ======  =======\n\n"  
#define REPORTCOLUMN1         "%s, %s\t%8.2f%8.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%9.2f\n"
#define REPORTCOLUMN2         "%32.2f%18.2f%8.2f\n\n"

extern void CalculateTaxes(float gross, float defr, float *ft, float *st, float *ssit);

int main()
{
    EmployeeRecord r;

    float reghours,ovthours; 
    float ft,st,ssit;
    float pr,reg,ovt,gp,fedt,stt,sst,def,np;
    float avgpr,avgreg,avgovt,avggp,avgfedt,avgstt,avgsst,avgdef,avgnp;
    char answer;
    int empCount;

     FILE *ReportFile;    
     ReportFile = fopen("report.txt", "w");
     fprintf(ReportFile,REPORTCOLUMNHEADINGS1);
     fprintf(ReportFile,REPORTCOLUMNHEADINGS2);
     fprintf(ReportFile,BARS);
     fclose(ReportFile);    

    empCount = 0;// count initializations   
    pr = reg = ovt = gp = fedt = stt = def = sst = np = 0;
    do
    {

      printf("Enter employee's name: ");  // input section
      scanf("%s%s",firstname,lastname);
      printf("Enter hourly pay rate: ");
      scanf("%f",ADDR(payrate));
      printf("Enter deferred amount: ");
      scanf("%f",ADDR(defr));
      printf("Enter hours worked this pay period: ");
      scanf("%f",ADDR(hours));
          if (hours > 40)
          {
               reghours = 40;
               ovthours = hours - 40;
          }
          else {
               reghours = hours;
               ovthours = 0;
          }      
      gross = (reghours * payrate)+(ovthours * payrate * 1.5);
      CalculateTaxes(gross,defr,&ft,&st,&ssit);//Call 3.5 CalculateTaxes 
      net = gross - ft - st - ssit;
      printf(REPORTCOLUMNHEADINGS1);
      printf(REPORTCOLUMNHEADINGS2);
      printf(BARS); 
      printf(REPORTCOLUMN1,lastname,firstname,payrate,reghours,gross,ft,ssit,net); 
      printf(REPORTCOLUMN2,ovthours,st,defr);   
          ReportFile = fopen("report.txt", "a");
          fprintf(ReportFile,REPORTCOLUMN1,lastname,firstname,payrate,reghours,gross,ft,ssit,net); 
          fprintf(ReportFile,REPORTCOLUMN2,ovthours,st,defr); 
          fclose(ReportFile);
      empCount = empCount + 1;
      pr = pr + payrate;
      fedt = fedt + ft;
        if (hours > 40)
          {
               reghours = 40;
               ovthours = hours - 40;
          }
          else {
               reghours = hours;
               ovthours = 0;
          }
      reg = reg + reghours;    
      ovt = ovt + ovthours;
      gp = gp + gross;
      stt = stt + st;
      sst = sst + ssit;
      np = np + net;
      def = def + defr;
      avgpr = pr / empCount;
      avgfedt = fedt / empCount;
      avgreg = reg / empCount;
      avgovt = ovt / empCount;
      avggp = gp / empCount;
      avgstt = stt / empCount;
      avgsst = sst / empCount;
      avgnp = np / empCount;
      avgdef = def / empCount;

          fflush(stdin);
          printf(" Repeat (Y/N)? : ");
          scanf("%c",ADDR(answer)); 
    } while (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');
        printf("\n"); // print one line for spacing 
   printf("\nTotals %17.2f%8.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%9.2f\n",pr,reg,gp,fedt,sst,np); 
   printf("%24.2f%10.2f%10.2f\n",ovt,stt,def); 
   printf("\nAverages %17.2f%8.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%9.2f\n",avgpr,avgreg,avggp,avgfedt,avgstt,avgnp); 
   printf("%24.2f%10.2f%10.2f\n",avgovt,avgsst,avgdef);
          ReportFile = fopen("report.txt", "a");
          fprintf(ReportFile,"\nTotals %17.2f%8.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%9.2f\n",pr,reg,gp,fedt,sst,np); 
          fprintf(ReportFile,"%32.2f%18.2f%8.2f\n",ovt,stt,def); 
          fprintf(ReportFile,"\nAverages %15.2f%8.2f%10.2f%8.2f%8.2f%9.2f\n",avgpr,avgreg,avggp,avgfedt,avgsst,avgnp); 
          fprintf(ReportFile,"%32.2f%18.2f%8.2f\n",avgovt,avgstt,avgdef);
          fclose(ReportFile);   
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the full error message, similar to how you have the full header and .c file.

Comment: Also, "#include "CalcTaxes.o"" What are you doing there? Unless that .o file isn't a .o file, you can't do that, and that should be throwing horrible errors from the compiler trying to parse a binary file.

Comment: Do you have a circular dependency?  Do you have two header files that are each trying to `#include` each other?  If so, that's the likely cause of your errors.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I have a header file and an object file that are being pulled in. However, the object file is pulling in a separate header file if that causes an issue.

Comment: @Tim The error messages are all the same. They say that "'firstname' undeclared (first use this function)" or "'lasname' undeclared (first use this function)" and so on. Basically does this for all variables in the header file.

Comment: Your `ADDR()` macro is not useful; using the `&` operator directly is a lot clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared a variable called firstname.

You have declared a structure type with firstname as a member, although I have never seen that syntax before, so I'm not sure it will work. All the examples I have ever seen have the type proceeding each variable with a semicolon on each line.

Perhaps you want to refer to r.firstname instead?